# Open Excel file in a app without installation of excel

Tags: android, ios, excel, vba

This is a general question for iOS and Android development. I want to consider if this is possible and gather thoughts from here.

You can imagine this app as a social network app and people can comment/add/edit on each other's post. I want users to add/upload an Excel file from their sides, and then I want other users to view this excel file inside app instead of jumping to Microsoft Excel APP in their phone.

In one sentence, just add an Excel view feature inside of my app. Do you think this is possible? Any existing resources?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Android you can use http://www.independentsoft.com/jspreadsheet/index.html

No clue about iOS or cross-platform-solutions though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's pretty useful!